I'm using Python with tkinter and need to use letters with diacritics and I need to know how to get them to center above or below
As an example of what I'm trying to do I want the small circle directly below the n to indicate a voiceless n. I've been trying to wrestle with this in tk inter for a few hours and I cannot get them to take up the same spot. I can only get it to show up before or after the letter.
Is it possible for it to show up directly below the letter like it should?

from tkinter import *

window = Tk()
window.config(bg="white")
window.geometry("350x150")
FONT_FOR_LABEL = ("@Arial Unicode MS", 56, "normal")

symbol_show = Button(window, text="n"+u"\u0325", font=FONT_FOR_LABEL, bg="white")
symbol_show.pack()

window.mainloop()

I have tried it by text and by unicode in both ways and have been looking for several hours for any way to combine these.

Probably a font issue. Checked several fonts, Arial seems to be one of worst offender in putting the "Combining Ring Below" off-center.

"@Arial Unicode MS" does not work for me because not listed in tkinter.font.families(). However, FONT_FOR_LABEL = ("Arial", 56, "normal") works…

This will look fine on Windows and macOS. There is a rendering issue on Linux (most likely X11). What you describe also happens when you use Indian and Arabic languages ​​in any widget that displays text. There is a workaround for Arabic. If you can't find any ready-made solution for your language, consider other GUI libraries with Python wrappers/bindings.

I tried about ten fonts the setting which without being in the font family is probably just going back to Arial is a last try. I should of put those steps in what I did. I am on linux though so the last comment about a rendering issue with x11 is interesting. Maybe that is my issue. I will try it on another os and see

You best bet is to ditch most GUI solutions in Python and look for one of the ones that are based on HTML/CSS solutions and use browser based rendering. Python GUI and TUI solutions traditionally have primitive font rendering capabilities.

Thank you Andj. That seems to be where I am also. I'll see what I can do with flask/html to build the UI.

I found out that the font "DejaVuSans" can display the string "h̃ l̥ r̥ n̥ m̥ ɲ̊ ŋ̊" on Linux Mint (not perfect, but it can). However, it is unknown whether the script itself will display correctly.
